# Angular 2, Does @Input with a setter behave differently than @Input without a setter?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I am wondering if someone could elaborate on this. Does `@Input()` with a setter vs using `@Input()` without a setter behave differently in regards to change detection?

**For example:**

```
@Input() something: SomeType;
```

*-vs-*

```
private _something;

@Input() set something(something: SomeType ) {
  this._something = something;
}

get something(): SomeType {
  return this._something;
}
```

The obvious difference is that the setter/getter allows `@Input()` with some extra logic. But does this affect change detection in a different way than if I were to use `@Input()` without a setter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For angular not a lot changes. The input won't be set or the setter won't be called more often. There is however a caveat where there is more logic inside the setter which can trigger another change detection. If you have that, angular will throw the known error (only in development mode)

> Expression has changed after it was checked.

So, the change detector does not behave differently, but issues may arise depending on what extra logic you put inside the setter

Comment: "If you have that, angular will throw the known error (only in development mode)" .. So `setTimeout()` or something like `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` inside the set function will always throw that error?

Comment: No no, those will actually prevent it from throwing. But if you set another property which is used inside a template from within the setter, there is a big chance you'll get that error.

Answer (score 3):

From angular's view, the only difference is that you got a chance to hook those `@Input()`'s get/set functions.

From Javascripts view, first will be "just" a property, second would use `Object.defineProperty`.

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/1koamZCvyG5YAIPNB73r?p=preview

compiled code with setter:

```js
Object.defineProperty(AppComponent.prototype, "test1", {
    get: function () { return this._test1; },
    set: function (val) {
        console.log('test1 was set!');
        this._test1 = val;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
__decorate([
    __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["Input"])(), 
    __metadata('design:type', Object), 
    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [Object]) /* difference? */
], AppComponent.prototype, "test1", null);
```

compiled code withOUT setter:

```js
__decorate([
    __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["Input"])(), 
    __metadata('design:type', Object)
], AppComponent.prototype, "test2", void 0);
```

both compiled with `angular-cli`: `ng build`.